# Fill blank space with Neat grid

Tags: html, css, bourbon, neat

I am using Bourbon Neat sass grid and we are trying to develop a simple template that has a sidebar on left and a content div on the right.

```
<section class="section">
  <div class="section__container">

    <nav class="side-menu">
      <ul class="side-menu__list">
        <li class="side-menu__list-item">
          <a class="side-menu__link side-menu__link--active" href="#">Typography</a>
        </li>
        <li class="side-menu__list-item">
          <a class="side-menu__link" href="#">Color scheme</a>
        </li>
        <li class="side-menu__list-item">
          <a class="side-menu__link" href="#">Icons</a>
        </li>
        <li class="side-menu__list-item">
          <a class="side-menu__link" href="#">Grid</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="working-area">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi nisi incidunt ad, recusandae, deserunt quos saepe tempora at natus? Ipsa quod harum, sequi ad unde repellendus nisi nostrum repellat totam.</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

We have this sass:

```
.section {
  @include grid-container;
}

.section__container {
  @include grid-column(8);
  @include grid-shift(2);
}

.working-area {
  @include grid-column(9);
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.side-menu {
  @include grid-column(3);
}
```

However the template always come with a `margin-left` and it doesn't fill the whole container. I couldn't find this information on their Docs page.

How to remove that `margin-left` and make the content fill the rest of the div?

I attach an image of what we have.
[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure Neat v2 uses the `grid-collapse` which can be used to change the margins of your container.  I'm not very experienced with Neat having only used it a small amount, but I would look through the docs and examine how `grid-collapse` works. It may be as simple as adding `@grid-collapse` to your `.working-area` selector.

Comment: You are right. I was able to fix it by using grid-collapse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neat v2 uses the `@grid-collapse` feature which can be used to eliminate the margins of your container. Read through the docs [here](http://neat.bourbon.io/docs/2.0.0/).

In your case, it should be as simple as adding @grid-collapse to your `.working-area` selector.